# View not updating to show another view when button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am pretty new to SwiftUI and I feel like I'm having trouble with something that feels like it would be very simple. Although, I have spent hours on this and need some assistance. I have my onboarding view. What I am attempting to do is when I tap the skip button it should display a transition view. I have the skip button toggling from true to false to show the transition screen. My problem is when I hit the skip button it will not refresh the onboarding view to display the transition screen.

**OnboardingView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct OnboardingView: View {
    
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    var onboardings: [Onboarding] = OnboardingData
    @State private var isAnimating: Bool = false
    @State private var showSplash = true
    @ObservedObject var showTransition = ShowTransition()
    
    //MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            if showSplash {
                SplashView()
                    .transition(.opacity)
                    .animation(.easeOut(duration: 1.5))
            } else if showTransition.showTransition == true {
                TransitionView()
            } else {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    ZStack {
                        Image("Endero Background-LightMode").resizable().aspectRatio(geometry.size, contentMode: .fill).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    }
                    
                    Text("Welcome")
                        .font(.system(size: 48, weight: .heavy))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                        .padding(.top, 23)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                TabView {
                    ForEach(onboardings[0...4]) { item in
                        OnboardingCardView(onboarding: item)
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3)
            {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showSplash = false
                }
            }
        }
    } // End Body
}
```

**OnboardingCardView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct OnboardingCardView: View {
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    var onboarding: Onboarding
    @State private var isAnimating: Bool = false
    
    //MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                //ONBOARDING: BODY
                Text(onboarding.body)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .font(.system(size: 32))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding(.top, 125)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                    .frame(maxWidth:480)
                
                //BUTTON: SKIP
                Spacer()
                    SkipButtonView()
                        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                        .padding(.bottom, 40)
            } //VStack
        } //ZStack
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                isAnimating = true
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        .background(Image(onboarding.background))
        .cornerRadius(26)
        .padding(.horizontal, 24)
        .padding(.top, 120)
        .padding(.bottom, 70)
    } //END BODY
}
```

**Skip Button View**

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

//MARK: - OBSERVABLES
class ShowTransition: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showTransition = false
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        cancellable = $showTransition
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
                self?.objectWillChange.send()
            }
    }
    
    func showTransitionToggle() {
        showTransition.toggle()
    }
}

struct SkipButtonView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    @AppStorage("isOnboarding") var isOnboarding: Bool?
    @ObservedObject var showTransition = ShowTransition()
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                showTransition.showTransitionToggle()
                print(showTransition.showTransition)
            }) {
                Text("SKIP")
                    .font(.system(size: 29))
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                
                    .background(
                        Capsule().strokeBorder(Color.white, lineWidth: 2.5).frame(width: 300, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                    )
                    .accentColor(Color.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I set the showTransition value to true at the start of the application it shows the transition screen. So I feel like the issue is when I hit the skip button to show the transition screen it is not refreshing the onboarding view to show the Transition view.

Comment: Maybe unrelated but the `init` method in `ShowTransition` is redundant. The class sends `objectWillChange` implicitly when `showTransition` changes.

Comment: Just remove the `ObservableObject`, there is no point in a Combine pipeline that immediately goes down the `sink`. Use `@Binding var` for write access to a state in subview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `ShowTransition` in `SkipButtonView` which is why the changes are't propagated to `OnboardingView`. To fix this, you could:

- Pass the `ShowTransition` object to `SkipButtonView`;
- Or use `EnvironmentObject` to inject `ShowTransition` into `SkipButtonView`:

```
//Injecting
.environmentObject(showTransition)

//Reading
@EnvironmentObject var showTransition: ShowTransition
```

**Note:** As [**@vadian**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian) pointed out, the `init` is unnecessary and `ShowTransition` simplifies to:

```
class ShowTransition: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showTransition = false
    func showTransitionToggle() {
        showTransition.toggle()
    }
}
```

## **Example passing the object:**

**SkipButtonView**:

```
struct SkipButtonView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    @AppStorage("isOnboarding") var isOnboarding: Bool?
    @ObservedObject var showTransition: ShowTransition //Update
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                showTransition.showTransitionToggle()
                print(showTransition.showTransition)
            }) {
                Text("SKIP")
                    .font(.system(size: 29))
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                
                    .background(
                        Capsule().strokeBorder(Color.white, lineWidth: 2.5).frame(width: 300, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                    )
                    .accentColor(Color.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OnboardingCardView**:

```
struct OnboardingCardView: View {
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    @ObservedObject var showTransition: ShowTransition //Updated
    var onboarding: Onboarding
    @State private var isAnimating: Bool = false
    
    //MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                //ONBOARDING: BODY
                Text(onboarding.body)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .font(.system(size: 32))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding(.top, 125)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                    .frame(maxWidth:480)
                
                //BUTTON: SKIP
                Spacer()
                SkipButtonView(showTransition: showTransition) //Updated
                    .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                    .padding(.bottom, 40)
            } //VStack
        } //ZStack
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                isAnimating = true
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        .background(Image(onboarding.background))
        .cornerRadius(26)
        .padding(.horizontal, 24)
        .padding(.top, 120)
        .padding(.bottom, 70)
    } //END BODY
}
```

**OnboardingView**:

```
struct OnboardingView: View {
    
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    var onboardings: [Onboarding] = OnboardingData
    @State private var isAnimating: Bool = false
    @State private var showSplash = true
    @StateObject var showTransition = ShowTransition() //Updated: use @StateObject for the root object
    
    //MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            if showSplash {
                SplashView()
                    .transition(.opacity)
                    .animation(.easeOut(duration: 1.5))
            } else if showTransition.showTransition == true {
                TransitionView()
            } else {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    ZStack {
                        Image("Endero Background-LightMode").resizable().aspectRatio(geometry.size, contentMode: .fill).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    }
                    
                    Text("Welcome")
                        .font(.system(size: 48, weight: .heavy))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                        .padding(.top, 23)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                TabView {
                    ForEach(onboardings[0...4]) { item in
                        OnboardingCardView(showTransition: showTransition, onboarding: item) //Updated
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3)
            {
            withAnimation {
                self.showSplash = false
            }
            }
        }
    } // End Body
}
```

Comment: Do you mind showing me how you would implement it within my code? I tried doing this and I'm still a little lost

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: I can not thank you enough. After seeing this it finally all makes sense! Works perfectly!

Comment: They should be using `@Binding` not `ObservableObject`.